# What's the origin of metaphor "to give someone ammo"?

Tags: etymology, metaphors

In last decade I often encounter this phrase used as "giving the opponent an argument in debate" while discussing an unfolding drama or conflict.

While I understand the meaning, I wonder how it come to be? Is it just a colloquial metaphor coming from idea that you need "ammo" to shoot or it got a literary source. The problem arose during performing formal translation of text, which should have been proof-readed. Proofreader used local officially approved dictionary which contained only one meaning for "ammo": supplies for firearms or artillery. In result figurative translation was refused as an illegal one. It could be accepted if errata to dictionary would be approved, but it cannot contain slang (don't ask me why).

If only "ammo" used in such meaning, the whole phrase might be slang or argo. **If "ammunition" got such meaning, my question is what proof of such could be used, with a source.**

Comment: Nothing colloquial about "ammunition" being a metaphor for useful arguing or debating points; plenty colloquial about "ammo" though. Plenty colloquial about "legit" too.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Pardon me  if I'm not catching drift of your terrific sarcasm. Yeah, I know that "legit" is informal form of legitimate, it was an intentional use because of slight difference in style. But I'm not a native speaker here and it's first time and only form of "ammo" used such way. Never found "ammunition" used, though.  What I'm curious about the history of such use.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey This curiosity is practical because it would give *me* ammunition to defend presence of that meaning in official dictionary. So far it getting declined as "slang".

Comment: But "ammo" _is_ slang/informal/colloquial. What is your question?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If only "ammo" used in such meaning,the whole meaning is slang. If ammunition (literary form) got such meaning, my question is of proof of such, with a source.

Comment: You mean like this? "facts that can be used to support an argument: His bad behaviour provided plenty of ammunition for his opponents."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey exactly

Comment: Is the dictionary not enough proof?

Comment: Figurative use of the phrase "give [an opponent] ammunition" goes back more than a century. Here is an example from a Kentucky newspaper published on September 1, 1909: "The insurgents [against Speaker of the House Joseph Cannon] themselves are rather pleased that the speaker treated them in this way [giving them undesirable committee assignments]—it **gives them more ammunition** for the next battle, and it only strengthens their contention that the greatest of all evils in the present government in the house [of Representatives] is the speaker's power of suppressing men on committees, ...

Comment: ...or in 'packing' the committees so that they will be pliant to his will." You can read this sentence in fuller context in the item titled "[Uncle Joe Cannon](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85052114/1909-09-01/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22gives%2Bthem%2Bmore%2Bammunition%22)" in the _Paducah [Kentucky] Evening Sun_. A similar instance appears in an Indianapolis, Indiana, newspaper from December 3, 1900: " I am not in favor of telling people throughout the State beforehand what you intend to do, as it **gives them ammunition** if they want to fight you."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oxford Dictionary of English, Third Edition, page 52:

> **ammunition** (noun) [mass noun] a supply or quantity of bullets and shells. considerations that can be used to support one's case in debate: *these figures provide ammunition to the argument for more resources*.

[image]

1645 quote for figurative use as in OP question in Oxford English Dictionary (First Edition, 1888).

> This Spirituall Ammunition [sic] shall sufficiently furnish the soul
> for her encounter with her last enemy.

[image]

Comment: Done with my phone.

Comment: I took care of it for you.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - _I know about images vs. actual text_. I provided a photo of the page in Oxford taken with my phone in response to OP's comment "Note , that speaker doesn't trust any online dictionary, official policy is that "wikipedia" and "wiktionary" are sources of false information, only printed sources do. "

Comment: Michael: I thought you weren't able to transcribe it, that's why I did. (You can roll-back, however.)

Comment: No, both is good.

Comment: Good, hopefully, I'll get it added to Mueller's dictionary (English-Russian one). Was issued since day immrmorial, yet never had this one. Odd thing it lists the word a verb too.

Comment: Yes, it can be a verb too.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the existing contributions, *to give someone ammo* is of course a war metaphor. War metaphors are a common and rich source of imagery.

I can, for example, imagine some politician saying something like:

- COVID-19 has now **launched its attack on home territory**.
- The region is **under fire** from the virus.
- Returning to normalcy following lockdown will be an **uphill battle**.

and so on.

More war metaphors: http://knowgramming.com/war_metaphors.htm

Comment: A good collection of analogies, but apparently that exact expression is unrelated to war but rather to a dated meaning of "ammunition"  - any kind of spiritual empowerment or motivation. So, "Lord, give me ammunition" isn't a prayer for an extra magazine.

Answer (score 2):

Ammo= Ammunition.

Ammunition=
1.a supply of bullets, shells, bombs, etc.
Ex: an explosion at an ammunition dump.

2.information that can be used in trying to win an argument.
Ex: the letter gave her all the ammunitions she needed.

Entries related to ammunition.
1.ammo 2.munition.

Ammunition, often called ammo, comes from the French word la munition.At first it meant all items used for war. This was from the Latin word munire (to provide).

"To give someone ammo" or "to give someone ammunition" means to say to someone something which he can use against you, or to do something.

Comment: The 2 . is exactly meaning I look for  to have proof that it should be official (for printed dictionary). The problem is I"m getting told it's "slang" and should not be added as legitimate meaning.

Comment: Ammo is an informal expression. Information expressions are used between friends or people who know each other well, in a relaxed or unofficial context.they are not appropriate for formal situations.

Comment: That's actually what I wrote in the question. Question is, what about meaning 2. of ammunition (provided ammo == ammunition). The argument against it that I was given "there no evidence of use of *ammunition* in that meaning and *ammo* is slang, so the meaning itself is slang." Note , that speaker doesn't trust any online dictionary, official policy is that "wikipedia" and "wiktionary" are sources of false information, only printed sources do.

Comment: This isn't attributed, and gives no information as to where and when the idiomatic usage arose / burgeoned.